# Facet_grid() with just one facet

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to have a graphic that looks like facet_grid but with just one face. That is, since I do not have variables enough to create facets, I would like to have a similar graphic, with the same kind of title, but with just one facet. Is it possible? Thanks!

Comment: `qplot(1,1) + facet_grid(~1)`

Comment: Thanks!!! This works! I tried something around this but did not get there. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want strips on the top and on the right, like in `facet_grid`, you could add two variables to the data set on the fly and use them like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(transform(mtcars, foo="bar", fizz="buzz"), 
       aes(wt, mpg)) +
  geom_point() + 
  facet_grid(fizz~foo)
```

[image]